# Is there a "quote" parameter in read.df in sparkR?

Tags: r, sparkr

I'm trying to import a csv using sparkR's `read.df` function. I'm using a comma as a delimiter. Unfortunately, one of my columns is a long string with commas in it so `read.df` delimits these strings.

In R, the `quote = "/""` parameter in `read.csv` solves this perfectly. Is there an equivalent parameter in sparkR's `read.df`?

Or is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: You could try using sparklyr's `read_csv`: https://rdrr.io/cran/sparklyr/man/spark_read_csv.html

Comment: This `read_csv` function does solve my problem but unfortunately, sparklyr does not support Spark version: 2.3.2.3.1.4.0